# How to add renderable Texture in Unity 3D for iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, textures

I am using Unity 3D and want to render an image on a texture, which should be stuck at one point, not stuck with the camera. How can I do that?

I am new to Unity.

Comment: I would take this question to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a plane or some sort of figure to hold that texture. You would then add a mesh renderer to that plane and assign the texture to that plane's renderer. In that way, the plane will "Hold" the texture and keep it at a specific point.

For example:

```
Texture2d texture = new Texture2d();
texture.mainTexture = ...
GameObject.Find("THE PLAIN'S NAME").renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
```

EDIT: For webcamtexture:

```
WebCamTexture texture = new WebcamTexture();
GameObject.Find("THE PLAIN'S NAME").renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
texture.Play();
```

Comment: I have done this sort of work, but didn't try exactly this approach. Actually I am doing this work with Live device camera.

Comment: @josh It is the same concept, you just use WebcamTexture. See my edit.